# How do I get the operation name from an opentracingsSpan?

Tags: go, opentracing

I'm using Go but I don't know if this question is generic to opentracing.

```
span, ctx := opentracing.StartSpanFromContext(ctx, "the_name")
```

Then later, given just the span variable, how do I retrieve the operationName "the_name"?  There is a SetOperationName() method but no GetOperationName().

Comment: add name as context value you passed to the `StartSpanFromContext`. and pass the `ctx` everywhere with span.

Comment: looking at the code it calls for https://github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go/blob/3088eee7e4d26010ac9a301e977fd2721dbebcbe/gocontext.go#L49 which in turns call for a bunch of things until  https://github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go/blob/3088eee7e4d26010ac9a301e977fd2721dbebcbe/globaltracer.go#L31 Adding that `Span` is an interface. so you could write a tracer that factory spans that are able to return the operation name. What is your current tracer ? Noop ? https://github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go/blob/3088eee7e4d26010ac9a301e977fd2721dbebcbe/globaltracer.go#L9  guess it is not.

Answer (score 0):

I searched the library, and it doesn't seem like there's a way to do what you are looking for. An alternative approach may be to create a hashmap, with span as the key and the name as the result.